# Uniform distribution of points

Tags: geometry-nodes

In Houdini, one of its own geometry nodes, the Scatter node, allows points to be distributed across a surface or through a volume in a roughly uniform pattern. That's done using an option called "Relax Iterations". Is there a way to have a uniform distribution of points across a mesh in Blender or would I have to generate the points on faces or vertices?

[image: HoudiniScatter]

[image: HoudiniScatter2]

Comment: Geonodes Point Distribution has a Poisson Disk option that lets you specify the minimum distance between instances

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blender has no "relax" out of the box, but you can try to recreate it by yourself using a set of nodes.

For the "Relax iterations" you can use repeat zone and relax points  like this:

[image]

Here is relaxing and sticking back to surface:

[image]

Then you can pack the nodes and reuse it:

[image]

[image]

Comment: How can I use a density map for the points?

Comment: @RobertHintz nope. With different radii, it is impossible, because long distance points will be stopped by short distance points. So that it should be another algorithm.

Comment: Even if I use the Join Geometry node?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of a solution that can take any input geometry and instances some cones.  You could instance any geometry by referencing it through the *Object Info* node.

[image]

If you need your input geometry as well you can just add a *Join Geometry* at the end and connect from the *Group Input*.

[image]

*Set Material* can be placed here to set the material for only the instanced geometry, if it happens to come from geonodes.  Otherwise, all the input or referenced geometry will have the materials you've set up normally.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Such type of point distribution can be achieved in **Geometry Nodes** with

**Distribute Points on Faces node**

Select the option **Poisson Disk** and tweak the **Density Max** (the maximal expected point density) and Distance Min (the minimum distance between any point). If 2 points are closer than that distance one of them is removed, creating more "relaxed and even distribution.

[image]